# Finding partial derivatives of a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, classical-mechanics

How would I find the partial derivatives of a function $$L(x(t), v(t), t)$$ where x and v are a function of time? I'm trying to derive the Euler-Lagrangian equation, and finding partial derivatives for $$x(t)+s \eta(t)$$ $$v(t)+s \eta(t)$$ of this expression:

$$ \frac{d}{ds} \int_{a}^{b} L(x(t)+s \eta(t),v(t)+s \eta(t),t) \, dt $$

seems too complex at the moment. Any hints? I know that in general, for $$L(x(t),y(t),z(t))$$
$$ \frac{dL}{dt}=\frac{dL}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dL}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{dL}{dz}\frac{dz}{dt} $$

But how do I apply that to this problem?

Comment: Hint: The $d/ds$ can pass into the integral since the bounds do not depend on $s$.  Then, just apply $d/ds$ to $L( \ldots )$.

Comment: Is the above equation for $$\frac{dL}{dt} $$ still valid for this problem?

Comment: @JimM: The derivatives $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$ etc. in your expression for $\frac{\mathrm dL}{\mathrm dt}$ should be partial derivatives. Unfortunately I don't quite understand what you're trying to do -- what does "finding partial derivatives for ... of this expression ..." mean? By "for" do you mean "with respect to"? If so, what do you mean by partial differentiation with respect to a function?